# I have REST API and want to reuse it for exposing differen format API on same server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, guice

I implemented and exposed REST API on my server. Now I need to expose same API, but I can't use REST (it's actually websocket messages), it will be some custom format. Don't ask why )

I imagine message transformation from my custom format to http request, then process it in my web-server, transform response back to my custom format, and send to client.

The simplest way is regular http call to localhost. For example (java):

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost/api/...").openConnection();
```

and so on, or using some http client library.
But I'm afraid there will be too much overhead, creating connection, etc.

Another ways:

1. I use Tomcat. Push my request directly to tomcat somehow.
2. I use Guice, and all requests go through GuiceFilter. Craft ServetRequest, ServletResponce and FilterChain objects and directly call GuiceFilter.doFilter.
3. I use GuiceContainer for Jersey. Some test frameworks use it for REST API testing, but also need to craft request/response objects.

There is no standard way to craft request object at all.
And I don't know on which level it's better to add my custom requests.

Hope I described my problem clearly.

Comment: Having an API that calls another API and also transforms the response message, will add overhead no matter what and it's more vulnerable to failure. If your business logic is well made, you could use it in both APIs, removing the dependency of A -> B.

Comment: Hi 414v32,
you're right, but REST api already has url mapping and I want to reuse it too. I thought to create one more code layer in my application that will be used by both API, but then I'll need to create one more mapping for command names of second API. It's code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

[Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) may be a good fit here. It's [allegedly](http://jaxenter.com/jsr-356-java-api-for-websocket-or-atmosphere-107316.html) compatible with both Resteasy and Jersey, so that's a plus, it simply adds WebSocket functionality on top of these.

Caveat: I haven't tried this myself, but came across it when looking for the same capability. :-)